# How do you open a batch file within a batch file, but in notepad?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

How do you open a batch (`.BAT`) file in `notepad` using an `if` statement in an already open version of the file? For example... You've entered the batch file and it's running through `cmd`, but then you type in a key word to open that same batch file, but in `notepad` - let's say, for a quick edit... How would you make that happen?

Let's say that the key word is `yum`.
My understanding is that you'd have to do the following, but I don't know further than that:

```
set /p input=
if %input%==yum goto open
:open
```

In `open` I don't know what code to write as I'm fairly new to coding, and I've look many places. If anyone could help, that'd be fantastic.

Comment: Try `if /I "%input%"=="yum" start "" notepad "%~f0"` reference [here](http://ss64.com/nt/) and [here](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this :

```
@echo off
set /p input=Enter something :
if %input%==yum notepad "%~f0"
```

This will wait until you exit notepad or

```
@echo off
set /p input=Enter something :
if %input%==yum start notepad "%~f0"
```

To open notepad in another thread.

Comment: `%~nx0` does not suffice. Need **1**. full path as current directory and batch directory could differ, and **2**. double quoted path `"%~f0"` (could contain spaces or another `cmd`-poisonous character).

Comment: Thanks JosefZ ! Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
goto begin

:open
notepad "%~F0"
echo Returned from edition
echo/

rem When edit, do NOT modify previous lines!

:begin
set /P "input=Enter word: "
if "%input%" equ "yum" goto open
echo You typed: "%input%"
pause
goto begin
```